# how to set django model field value to automatically calculate a value based on values of other field in the different model

Tags: django

I am trying to figure out how I can make a django field model to automatically populate by summing values of another model's fields. For Example, if I have a model with 2 fields (first, second) and I want to automatically sum them and input them in a other model.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSNPA.png)

Comment: What would be the trigger? At what moment do you want the third field to get the value of the sum of the other two?

Comment: Is a model property not an option? It's gonna be tricky to maintain this value. It's probably better to just calculate this when you need it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make two tables with ForeignKey,

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    First = models.IntegerField()
    Second = models.IntegerField()

class Model2(models.Model):
    Model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    Sum = models.IntegerField()
```

then you can do it with normal views like this :

```
def saveSum(request):
    first = 5
    second = 6
    model1 = Model1(first=first,second=second)
    model1.save()
    
    #then sum the values and save it to the second model
    sum = first + second
    model2 = Model2(Model1=model1,sum=sum)
    model2.save()
```

or you can do it with SIGNALS and this is simple tutorial for this but be carefull with signals : [Click this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html)